# Asymptotic analysis, Upper bound

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

I have some confusion regarding the Asymptotic Analysis of Algorithms.

I have been trying to understand this upper bound case, seen a couple of youtube videos. In one of them, there was an example of this equation
where we have to find the upper bound of the equation `2n+3`. So, by looking at this, one can say that it is going o be  `O(n).`

**My first question** :
In algorithmic complexity, we have learned to drop the constants and find the dominant term, so is this Asymptotic Analysis to prove that theory? or does it have other significance? otherwise, what is the point of this analysis when it is always going to be the biggest `n` in the equation, example- if it were `n+n^2+3`, then the upper bound would always be `n^2`  for some `c` and `n0.`

**My second question** :
as per rule the upper bound formula in Asymptotic Analysis must satisfy this condition  `f(n) = O(g(n))` IFF `f(n) < c.g(n)` where `n>n0,c>0, n0>=1`

i) `n` is the no of inputs, right? or does `n` represent the number of steps we perform? and does `f(n)` represents the algorithm?

ii) In the [following video](https://youtu.be/1tfdr1Iv6JA?t=672) to prove upper bound of the equation `2n+3` could be `n^2` the presenter considered `c =1`, and that is why to satisfy the equation  `n` had to be `>= 3` whereas one could have chosen `c= 5`  and `n=1` as well, right? So then why were, in most cases in the video, the presenter was changing the value of `n` and not `c` to satisfy the conditions? is there a rule, or is it random? Can I change either `c` or `n(n0)` to satisfy the condition?

**My Third Question**:
In the same video, the presenter mentioned `n0` (n not) is the number of steps. Is that correct? I thought `n0` is the limit after which the graph becomes the upper bound (after `n0`, it satisfies the condition for all values of `n`); hence `n0` also represents the input.

Would you please help me understand because people come up with different ideas in different explanations, and I want to understand them correctly?

### Edit

---

The accepted answer clarified all of the questions except the first one. I have gone through many articles on the web, and here I am documenting my conclusion if anyone else has the same question. This will help them.

My first question was

> In algorithmic complexity, we have learned to drop the constants and
> find the dominant term, so is this Asymptotic Analysis to prove that
> theory?

No, Asymptotic Analysis describes the algorithmic complexity, which is all about understanding or visualizing the Asymptotic behavior or the tail behavior of a function or a group of functions by plotting mathematical expression.
In computer science, we use it to evaluate (note: evaluate is not measuring) the performance of an algorithm in terms of input size.

for example, these two functions belong to the same group

```
mySet = set()
def addToMySet(n):
    for i in range(n):
        mySet.add(i*i)

mySet2 = set()
def addToMySet2(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(500):
            mySet2.add(i*j)
```

Even though the execution time of the `addToMySet2(n)` is always > the execution time of `addToMySet(n)`, the tail behavior of both of these functions would be the same with respect to the largest `n`, if one plot them in a graph the tendency of that graph for both of the functions would be linear thus they belong to the same group. Using Asymptotic Analysis, we get to see the behavior and group them.

A mistake that I made assuming upper bound represents the worst case. In reality, The upper bound of any algorithm is associated with all of the best, average, and worst cases. so the correct way of putting that would be

> `upper`/`lower` bound in the `best`/`average`/`worst` case of an
> algorithm

.
We can't relate the upper bound of an algorithm with the worst-case time complexity and the lower bound with the best-case complexity. However, an upper bound can be higher than the worst-case because upper bounds are usually asymptotic formulae that have been proven to hold.

I have seen this kind of question like find the worst-case time complexity of such and such algorithm, and the answer is either `O(n)` or `O(n^2)` or `O(log-n)`, etc.

For example, if we consider the function `addToMySet2(n)`, one would say the algorithmic time complexity of that function is `O(n)`, which is technically wrong because there are three factors `bound`, `bound type`, (inclusive upper bound and strict upper bound) and `case` are involved determining the algorithmic time complexity.

When one denote `O(n)` it is derived from this Asymptotic Analysis `f(n) = O(g(n)) IFF for any c>0, there is a n0>0 from which f(n) < c.g(n) (for any n>n0)` so we are considering `upper bound` of `best/average/worst` case. In the above statement the `case` is missing.

I think We can consider, **when not indicated, the big O notation generally describes an asymptotic upper bound on the worst-case time complexity.** Otherwise, one can also use it to express asymptotic upper bounds on the average or best case time complexities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of asymptotic analysis is to compare algorithms performance scaling. For example, if I write two version of the same algorithm, one with `O(n^2)` time complexity and the other with `O(n*log(n))` time complexity, I know for sure that the `O(n*log(n))` one will be faster when n is "big". How big? it depends. You actually can't know unless you benchmark it. What you know is at some point, the `O(n*log(n))` will always be better.

Now with your questions:

1. the "lower" `n` in `n+n^2+3` is "dropped" because it is negligible when `n` scales up compared to the "dominant" one. That means that `n+n^2+3` and `n^2` behave the same *asymptotically*. It is important to note that even though 2 algorithms have the same time complexity, it does not mean they are as fast. For example, one could be always 100 times faster than the other and yet have the exact same complexity.
2. (i) `n` can be anything. It may be the size of the input (eg. an algorithm that sorts a list) but it may also be the input itself (eg. an algorithm that give the n-th prime number) or a number of iteration, etc
3. (ii) he could have taken any `c`, he chose `c=1` as an example as he could have chosen `c=1.618`. Actually the correct formulation would be:

`f(n) = O(g(n))` IFF `for any c>0, there is a n0>0 from which f(n) < c.g(n) (for any n>n0)`

3. the `n0` from the formula is a pure mathematical construct. For `c>0`, it is the `n` value from which the function `f` is bounded by `g`. Since `n` can represent anything (size of a list, input value, etc), it is the same for `n0`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. one small confusion, from what I understand that `0(n)` ,  `Ω(n)`  `θ(n)` can be the same , if we take the same example of `2n+3` the upper, lower and average bound are always going to be the same with respect to different `c`,`c1` and `n0`. is not this the same for every other equation? this is super confusing.

Comment: like if I consider this function `func(n){for i in 1..n{print (n)}}` is not the  upper bound, lower bound and average bound going to be `n` (`0(n) , Ω(n) θ(n)`)? for some  values of `c1`, `c2`?

Comment: `c` really has really no meaning, it is just part of a mathematical definition, the same way you would say `x` in `f(x)`. In your function the execution time is constant (always n loops). This is not always the case. For example the quicksort algorithm average complexity is O(n*log(n)) yet the worst case scenario is O(n^2). This happens when the list is already sorted